# How to group a data frame by variables that are approximately the same?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame with data for each county:

```
    A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   countyfips, day_after_reopening, deciles_income [6]
  countyfips day_after_reopening deciles_income winner2016  
       <int> <drtn>                       <int> <chr>       
1       1001 -109 days                        8 Donald Trump
2       1001 -102 days                        8 Donald Trump
3       1001  -95 days                        8 Donald Trump
4       1001  -88 days                        8 Donald Trump
5       1001  -81 days                        8 Donald Trump
6       1001  -74 days                        8 Donald Trump
```

And I would like to group it by the day_after_reopening column. However, the problem is that for each county the day_after_reopening number differs a little, as the observations are taken at the same time for each county, but the counties each opened on a different day of the week (e.g.out of the two counties I would like to have in the same group, one might have -109, the other -108).

How would you group these two counties with very similar numeric values together? Thank you.

Comment: First, what's the point of the grouping? What do you plan to do after? 

Good idea would probably be to create a new variable that lumps various time frames together - 0-25, 26-50, etc...or do by quartiles...you can use case_when to make that variable. Then you can group by that new variable.

Comment: do you have a specific threshold in mind or do you want it to be data driven? if it is data driven maybe try the function called `cut()`

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by data driven, but I would like to split it based on 7 day intervals beginning at 0. @Mike

Comment: I would like to split it based on 7 day intervals beginning at 0. @gregdubrow

Comment: So you want a variable, let's call it day_after_group, that's 0-6, 7-13, 14-20, etc? I think the cut() function may do it. Might help to do a fake example dataframe as a reprex, so you can show a snippet of the desired outcome.

Comment: @gregdubrow yes that is what I meant. Sorry I don' t know how to work with reprex but basically I would like each group to contain observations for counties that are 0-6 days after reopening, then 7-13 days after reopening etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create artificial groups based on some pre defined difference between numbers.

I created one example below:

```
require(dplyr)

# Difference max that you want
difference_max <- 2

# Create dummy data frame
day_after_reopening <- c(108, 109, 107, 50, 51, 68, 69, 67, 108, 109, 55, 56, 57, 100, 101, 101, 100,56)
df <- data.frame(day_after_reopening = day_after_reopening, index = seq(1:length(day_after_reopening)))

# Order the interesting column
df <- df[order(df$day_after_reopening),]
df$test <- c(diff(df$day_after_reopening, lag = 1), 0)

# Create the breaks where the difference value is greater than a selected value
breaks <- df[df$test > difference_max,]
breaks$test <- "here"
df <- rbind(breaks, df)
df <- df[order(df$day_after_reopening, df$test),]

# Create the split points and grouping
 df <- df %>% 
        mutate(split_point = test < "here",
              breaks = with(rle(split_point), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
        filter(split_point) %>% 
        group_by(breaks) %>%
        summarise(day_after_reopening_mean = mean(day_after_reopening))
 
    > df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  breaks day_after_reopening_mean
   <int>                    <dbl>
1      1                     50.5
2      3                     56  
3      5                     68  
4      7                    100. 
5      9                    108.
```

Comment: that could work if there were larger differences between the days but I fear that there will only be differences of one day between the variables (as it is a large dataset, containing hundreds of us counties).

Comment: But you can break the data between any difference: 2, 1 or 0.1 day. But I don't know if this little differences could identify groups. It was what I understud.

Comment: Know I understud your fear, if the difference is just 1 day in a big data frame, you could identify just one group. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then sounds like you'll first want to get the max number of days so you know how far to go out, and code for a new dataframe could be something like below (I've never used cut() so wouldn't know how to do it a bit more automatically):

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
mutate(day_after_grp = 
   case_when(day_after_reopening >=0 & day_after_reopening <=6 ~ "0-6",
        day_after_reopening >=7 & day_after_reopening <=13 ~ "7-13",
        day_after_reopening >=14 & day_after_reopening <=20 ~ "14-20",
```

etc to max. You'd then have a new variable "day_after_grp" to use for groupings.

Again, there may be a more programmatic way to do it w/ less copy/paste.