# Group column values by a set numeric difference in R (big dataset)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, data-wrangling

I want a script to put column values in groups with a maximum range of 10. So that all values in the group are <10 different from each other. I'm trying to get a script that defines the groups, counts how many values are in each group, and find the mean.

So if I had this df:

```
cat1 = c(85, 60, 60, 55, 55, 15, 0, 35, 35 )
cat2 = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
df <- data.frame(cat1, cat2)

  cat1 cat2
1   85    a
2   60    a
3   60    a
4   55    a
5   55    a
6   15    a
7    0    a
8   35    a 
9   35    a
```

the output would be:

```
numValues cat1avg 
      1    85
      4    57.5
      1    15
      1     0
      2    35
```

I followed the top-rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527242/how-to-group-a-data-frame-by-variables-that-are-approximately-the-same), but I'm getting weird outputs on some of my groups. Specifically, it doesn't seem like the script is properly adding the number of values in each group.

The only way I can think to do it is through for loops with a million if statements, and I have 1,000+ of these little dfs that I need to summarise.

I was also thinking of doing a fuzzy count. But I haven't been able to find anything about that anywhere either.

I also can't just cut up the cat1 range into groups of 10 and just allocate them all into a bin because it's less about the level and more about how close they are to each other.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it not work to group by 10s? ie `df %>%  group_by(cat1_floor = 10*floor(cat1/10)) %>%  summarize(numValues = n(), cat1avg = mean(cat1))`

Comment: @JonSpring if I did that, and I had cat1 values of 10 and 15, they wouldn't group together when I want them to - right?

Comment: 10 and 15 and 19 would be in one group, anything from 20-29 would be another, etc.

Comment: @JonSpring I realised that might be the case after I sent it. Say I wanted 9 and 15 to group together - that wouldn't happen right?

Comment: Suppose you have 9, 14, and 19, is there a reason 9+14 would be better than 9+15? Are you trying to make the bins of equal-ish size?

Comment: @JonSpring, that's a great question, and honestly, I'm not sure. My issue may actually be that I'm looking for the wrong thing. The numbers correspond to heights, but their measurements have a margin of error of 10. I'm trying to determine how many distinct heights there are, how many are in each group, and what the average group height is. - perhaps this is wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a good place for kmeans -- see this tutorial: https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/statistics/k-means/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest working at this in the opposite order. Instead of assigning groups based on distance and seeing how many groups there are, we could specify a number of groups (`k`) and ask R to pick the most distinct clusterings, and compare how well those clusterings fit our purpose. There is a built-in algorithm in R, `kmeans`, to do this for us.

Let's say we expect between 1 and 6 groups. There are only 6 unique values when I run `unique(cat1)` so it can't be more than that. We can then use `map` from `purrr` in `tidyverse` to use each of 1:6 in a kmeans algorithm, and we can use `augment` from `broom` to extract the output from that in a tidy way.

```
library(tidyverse); library(broom)
kclusts <- tibble(k = 1:6) %>%
  mutate(kclust = map(k, ~kmeans(cat1, .x)),
         augmented = map(kclust, augment, df)
  )
```

This will create a nested table with the results we want inside the `augmented` column. Let's pull those out:

```
assignments <- kclusts %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(augmented))
```

We could visualize these like so. Note that with k = 1, everything is in cluster 1. With k = 5, the 55 + 60s are paired. I think the trivial k = 6 case is just left out.

```
ggplot(assignments, aes(x = cat1, y = cat2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = .cluster), alpha = 0.8) + 
  facet_wrap(~ k)
```

[image]

We could see how much range is in each cluster produced in each case, and find the widest range cluster for each `k`. We see that dividing into four groups would have at least 15 range (see the `4` facet in the chart above), but 5 groups would be adequate to keep the within-cluster range under 5.

```
assignments %>%
  group_by(k, .cluster) %>%
  summarize(range = max(cat1) - min(cat1)) %>%
  summarize(max_range = max(range))

# A tibble: 6 × 2
      k max_range
  <int>     <dbl>
1     1        85
2     2        35
3     3        30
4     4        15
5     5         5
6     6         0
```

And finally:

```
assignments %>%
  filter(k == 5) %>%
  group_by(.cluster) %>%
  summarize(numValues = n(),
            cat1avg = mean(cat1))


  .cluster numValues cat1avg
  <fct>        <int>   <dbl>
1 1                1    85  
2 2                1    15  
3 3                2    35  
4 4                4    57.5
5 5                1     0
```

Comment: That's solved it perfectly - thank you! I was stuck for a while whenever it came to summarize, until I saw I just had to sub the "z" in summarize for an s (British English)- thanks again !!

Comment: (`summarise` and `summarize` are both supported; the original creator of `dplyr` is from New Zealand where they mostly use UK spelling.)